# Angular 13 routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

i added a privacy page that i need users to go to directly by either clicking a link on the login page or by typing the url directly in the browser.  when clicking the link the page routes no problem. the link routes to sitename.com/privacy

when typing that directly in the browswer i get an error in the console " Unexpected end of JSON input".   i have another page Support that is set up exactly like privacy and i can type that url (sitename.com/loginsupport)  directly into the browser and it routes with no problem.

another note: when testing locally , i type the url directly in the browser (http://localhost:4200/privacy) and it routes without error

i have this in LoginRoutes:

```
export const LOGIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent }, 
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { title: 'Login' } },
    { path: 'loginsupport', component: SupportComponent, data: { title: 'Support' } }, 
    { path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
];
```

in app-routing.module

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },  
            { path: '', component: AppComponent, children: LOGIN_ROUTES },
```

any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: please check whether your issue is reproducing in stackblitz or not... also provide that link here to work on

Comment: Not an answer, but in the future, try generating your pages using `ng g module login --module account --route login`. Only import the modules you actually need on this specific page. This makes your app load faster. Also check out `PreloadAllModules`

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this by deleting the components and routing information and redoing it all. i have no idea what the problem was the first time. i dont see anything different.